# Est-ce que « Est-que » est une forme correcte?

Tags: grammaire, questions, locutions, interrogative, constructions

J'ai trouvé cette phrase dans un cahier de grammaire :

> Est-que vous préférez travailler en été ou en hiver?

Après avoir cherché « est-que » sur Google pendant quelques minutes et y en trouvant rien, je suis arrivé à la conclusion que c'est une erreur dans le texte. Peut-on confirmer que ce soit une erreur? Sinon, quelles sont les différences entre

> Est-ce que

et

> Est-que

?

Comment: Probablement une simple erreur de frappe passée à travers les filets de la relecture...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Est-ce que* est le seul valable pour la forme interrogative : le *que* renvoyant à une situtation venant après l'interrogation.

> Est-ce qu'il pleut ?

*[Est-ce que](http://grammaire.reverso.net/3_1_27_est-ce_que.shtml)* est la tournure réservée à *l'interrogation directe*, c'est-à-dire au cas où l'on pose directement une question sans la rapporter, sans la faire dépendre d'un autre verbe, d'un autre terme.

L'interrogation *pleut-il ?* est la forme interrogative la plus simple pour poser la même question, elle est moins usité dans la conversation courante :

- *est-ce que* indique que l'on va poser une question, que l'on attire l'attention sur ce qui va suivre, que l'on veut impliquer l'attention de la personne que l'on interroge.
- la forme interrogative simple est une recherche d'information qui demande souvent une réponse binaire : oui, non.

Comment: Aussi des exemples au [Trésor](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/est-ce%20que).